# Translate synced models in Django with ModelTranslation

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n, django-modeltranslation

I am using [ModelTranslation](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/) to translate the contents of my models.

However, before starting to use the library I already did `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

I followed the instructions but `makemigrations` does not recognize any changes, as they have already been migrated.

The documentation says

> you can use a little helper: The sync_translation_fields Command which can execute schema-ALTERing SQL to add new fields.

but even `sync_translation_fields` says `No new translatable fields detected`.

How do I translate my already migrated models with ModelTranslation?

Comment: Did you finded a solution? I've put the translation.py in my app folder,

Comment: I figure out! I was putting the translation.py in the wrong place :P

Answer (score 0):

I had also added `translation.py` to the wrong directory.

It should be placed in the application dir.